# how to define model name in a for loop?

Tags: r

I want to train n random forest on different samples. sample 1 gives rf1, sample 2 gives rf2, etc.

BUT this kind of code doesn't work (error object of type 'closure' is not subsettable)

```
for (i in 1:3) {
       rf$i <- train(Y~.,data=trainingData,method="rf",
              ntree = 100,
              tuneGrid=data.frame(mtry = mtry),
              trControl = controle,
              metric='ROC')
}
```

How can I create the n random forest models?
Yours sincerely
Loïc

Comment: `$` doesn't work with variables after the `$`. Assuming `rf` is a list (initialize with `rf <- list()`), you use `[[` to assign, `rf[[i]] <- ...`

Comment: initilise a list called `rf = vector('list', 3)`, then use `rf[[i]] <- train(....)` in a loop

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because `rf` does not exist yet and you can't subset it.

**1. Use a list as a container**

The following should work.

```
# define the length of your random forest trials
N = 3
rf = vector( "list", N)
for (i in seq_len( N ) {
   rf[[ i ]] <- train( Y ~. , data = trainingData, method = "rf",
          ntree = 100,
          tuneGrid=data.frame(mtry = mtry),
          trControl = controle,
          metric='ROC')
}
```

The above code stores a list `rf` which contains three element according to `N`. You can access to each object with `rf[[ 1 ]]`, `rf[[ 2 ]]`, `rf[[ 3 ]]`.

**2. Store objects independently**

If you want to physically store independent `rf` objects in your Global Enviroment, the you have to use `assign()` as follows:

```
# define the length of your random forest trials
N = 3
for (i in seq_len( N ) {
       assign( paste0( "rf", i) ,
               train( Y ~. , 
                      data = trainingData, method = "rf",
                      ntree = 100,
                      tuneGrid=data.frame(mtry = mtry),
                      trControl = controle,
                      metric='ROC')
    }
```

This stores three objects `rf1`, `rf2`, and `rf3` in your environment and you can work on them independently.